# Why can `__subclasshook__` be monkeypatched onto the metaclass but `__instancecheck__` cannot?

Tags: python, interface, subclass, abc

Here is a toy example of trying to create a decorator that allows declaration of attribute names which should be required parts of "interface checking" along the standard `__subclasshook__` and `__instancecheck__` patterns.

It seems to work as expected when I decorate the `Foo` class. I make a `Bar` class, unrelated to `Foo`, but which has the needed attributes, and it correctly satisfies `isinstance(instance_of_bar, Foo) == True`.

But then as another example, I make a subclass of `dict` augmented so that the `key` values will be accessible with `getattr` syntax as well (e.g. a `dict` where `d['a']` can be replaced with `d.a` to get the same result). In this case, the attributes are just instance attributes, so `__instancecheck__` should work.

Here is the code. Note that given that the example with the instance of `Bar` works, the choice to "monkeypatch" the `__subclasshook__` function into the `Foo` class (that has a metaclass) works fine. So it does *not* seem that one must define the function directly in the class definition of the metaclass.

```
#Using Python 2.7.3

import abc
def interface(*attributes):
    def decorator(Base):

        def checker(Other):
            return all(hasattr(Other, a) for a in attributes)

        def __subclasshook__(cls, Other):
            if checker(Other):
                return True
            return NotImplemented

        def __instancecheck__(cls, Other):
            return checker(Other)

        Base.__subclasshook__ = classmethod(__subclasshook__)
        Base.__instancecheck__ = classmethod(__instancecheck__)
        return Base

    return decorator

@interface("x", "y")
class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    def x(self): return 5
    def y(self): return 10

class Bar(object):
    def x(self): return "blah"
    def y(self): return "blah"

class Baz(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "blah"
        self.y = "blah"

class attrdict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]

f = Foo()
b = Bar()
z = Baz()
t = attrdict({"x":27.5, "y":37.5})

print isinstance(f, Foo)
print isinstance(b, Foo)
print isinstance(z, Foo)
print isinstance(t, Foo)
```

Prints:

```
True
True
False
False
```

This is just a toy example -- I'm not looking for better ways to implement my `attrdict` class. The `Bar` example demonstrates the monkeypatched `__subclasshook__` working. The other two examples demonstrate failure of `__instancecheck__` for instances that have mere instance attributes to check on. In those cases, `__instancecheck__` is not even called.

I can manually check that the condition from my `__instancecheck__` function is satisfied by the instance of `attrdict` (that is, `hasattr(instance_of_attrdict, "x")` is `True` as needed) or `z`.

Again, it seems to work fine for the instance of `Bar`. This suggests that `__subclasshook__` is being correctly applied by the decorator, and that patching a custom `__metaclass__` is not the issue. But `__instancecheck__` does not seem to be called in the process.

Why can `__subclasshook__` be defined outside of the class definition of the metaclass and added later, but not `__instancecheck__`?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with built-in types. The `Other` parameter to `__subclasshook__` is the *class*, not an instance of the class. If you replaced `attrdict` with a class named `Baz` that assigned `self.x` and `self.y` in its `__init__` method, you'd get the exact same results because the class itself doesn't have those attributes, but an instance of it does.

Comment: But why wouldn't `__subclasshook__` (by virtue of `hasattr(Other, a)` returning `False` since I incorrectly try to use `Other` like an instance instead of a class) just return `False` then, instead of the `AssertionError` that I am seeing. And the follow-up is then: how do I use `__subclasshook__` to define checking on whether *instances* happen to have the required attributes to be considered an instance, whether such attributes were monkeypatched, created as class attributes, created as instance attributes in `__init__` or anything else.

Comment: Your code shouldn't work in the first place, as `all()` returns a boolean, which has no `next()` method. The `AssertionError` just says that `__subclasshook__` is expecting the return type to be boolean, while you're returning something else. `__instancecheck__` is what you really should be implementing.

Comment: Have you tried it? `all(...generator_expression...)` does work.

Comment: My original hope was the `all` would work around a generator expression the same way, e.g. `sum` does. I'm also puzzled by this. Why does `sum(x for x in [1,2,3])` return `6` whereas `all(x for x in [1,2,3])` returns a generator expression object?

Comment: Further, changing it to `all([hasattr(Other, a) for a in attributes])`, which definitely returns a `bool`, didn't help.

Comment: `all(x for x in [1,2,3])` returns `True` for me on both Python 2.7.5 and Python 3.3

Comment: I'm using 2.7.3 and it absolutely doesn't return `True` for me. It returns a generator object.

Comment: That's really strange and definitely should not be happening. What does `all is __builtin__.all` output?

Comment: You are correct. I'm in an IPython interpreter and somehow `all` is masked by `<function numpy.core.fromnumeric.all>` even though I meticulously guard my import statements and my IPython config files. I'm guessing it must be a property of the ipython binary managed by the IT team or something really crazy.

Comment: That fixes my other errors too. If I use `__builtin__.all`, then cases (1) and (2) return `True`. So now the question is just how to check whether instances themselves satisfy an interface. And it seems that `instancecheck` is the right method for that, so that `__subclasshook__` can be saved for just class-level checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works as is should. If you are using `__metaclass__`, you are overwriting the class creation process. It looks like your monkeypatch is working for `__subclasshook__` but it's only called from the `__subclasshook__` function of the `ABCMeta`. You can check it with this:

```
>>> type(Foo)
<class 'abc.ABCMeta'>
```

To be more explicit: the `__subclasshook__` case works by accident in this example, because the metaclass's `__subclasscheck__` happens to defer to the class's `__subclasshook__` in some situations. The `__instancecheck__` protocol of the metaclass does not ever defer to the class's definition of `__instancecheck__`, which is why the monkeypatched version of `__subclasshook__` does eventually get called, but the monkeypatched version of `__instancecheck__` does not get called.

In more details: If you are creating a class with the metaclass, the type of the class will be the metaclass. In this case the `ABCMeta`. And the definition of the `isinstance()` say the following: *'isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool'*, which means the instance checking will be executed on the given class, type or tuple of classes/types. In this case the isinstance check will be done on the `ABCMeta` (`ABCMeta.__instancecheck__()` will be called). Because the monkeypatch was applied to the `Foo` class and not the `ABCMeta`, the `__instancecheck__` method of `Foo` will never run. But the `__instancecheck__` of the `ABCMethod` will call the `__subclasscheck__` method of itself, and this second method will try the validaion by executing the `__subclasshook__` method of created class (in this example `Foo`).

In this case you can get the desired behavior if you overwrite the functions of the metaclass like this:

```
def interface(*attributes):
    def decorator(Base):

        def checker(Other):
            return all(hasattr(Other, a) for a in attributes)

        def __subclasshook__(cls, Other):
            if checker(Other):
                return True
            return NotImplemented

        def __instancecheck__(cls, Other):
            return checker(Other)

        Base.__metaclass__.__subclasshook__ = classmethod(__subclasshook__)
        Base.__metaclass__.__instancecheck__ = classmethod(__instancecheck__)
        return Base

    return decorator
```

And the output with the updated code:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Another approach would be to define your own class to serve as the metaclass, and create the kind of `__instancecheck__` protocol that you're looking for, so that it *does* defer to the class's definition of `__instancecheck__` when the metaclass's definition hits some failure criteria. Then, set `__metaclass__` to be *that* class inside of `Foo` and your existing decorator should work as-is.

More info: [A good post about metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/2710223)

Comment: This is a good workaround, but not an answer to the question. If I were to write my class definition of `Foo` with "@classmethod ... def __instancecheck__(...)" then it works. Same for `__subclasshook__`. So defining these functions as classmethods *for `Foo` itself* **does** work. Monkeypatching them onto `Foo` also works -- for `__subclasshook__` (again, never needing to apply it to `__metaclass__` as you did). So, given all that, why doesn't the same procedure also work for `__instancecheck__`? In other words, there's a difference between the two with no documented reason to expect one.

Comment: This is not a workaround. In your example you are creating an instance of `ABCMeta` and not from `Foo` (you can see it in thy `type(Foo)` example. And because it's an instance of `ABCMeta`, it will act like the `ABCMeta`. You can see the source of it here: [link](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/abc.py) The two method is defined here and when you are calling `isinstance`, this method will be executed. So if you want to overwrite the method, you have to overwrite/monkeypatch this and not the method of original `Foo` (because it's act like `Foo` but it's not the `Foo` itself).

Comment: I believe that the fact that my `__subclasshook__` works after monkeypatching illustrates that it is correctly being defined as the *metaclass's* function, not "`Foo`s". I agree with you about printing `type(Foo)` and seeing `ABCMeta` -- that's not surprising to me; it is expected. I'm not sure what your point is about that. Even after re-reading your answer and comment, my question still remains.

Comment: The `ABCMeta` has 2 (relevant for now) function: `__instancecheck__` and `__subclasscheck__`. But you can see: `__subclasscheck__` != `__subclasshook__`. You can define `__subclasshook__` function for `Foo` and this `__subclasshook__` will be called from `__subclasscheck__` (Line no. 161). You are monkeypatching the `Foo` but not the function what is called (`__subclasscheck__`) because the called method is in the `ABCMeta` class. And still: you cannot overwrite the `__instancecheck__` method of `ABCMeta` from `Foo`.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. So the difference is that in the `__instancecheck__` protocol, it never has a failure mode where it defers to that subclass's definition of `__instancecheck__`? Whereas, `ABCMeta`'s definition of `__subclasshook__` *does* defer to the subclass's definition of `__subclasshook__`?

Comment: I edited your answer to add more explicit statement of your point. Please review it to make sure I understood you correctly and that my two additions are correct. If you agree, then I will accept the answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ack from me. I added 1 more paragraph.